# Update multiple objects at once in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am using Django 1.9. I have a Django table that represents the value of a particular measure, by organisation by month, with raw values and percentiles:

```
class MeasureValue(models.Model):
    org = models.ForeignKey(Org, null=True, blank=True)
    month = models.DateField()
    calc_value = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    percentile = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
```

There are typically 10,000 or so per month. My question is about whether I can speed up the process of setting values on the models.

Currently, I calculate percentiles by retrieving all the measurevalues for a month using a Django filter query, converting it to a pandas dataframe, and then using scipy's `rankdata` to set ranks and percentiles. I do this because pandas and `rankdata` are efficient, able to ignore null values, and able to handle repeated values in the way that I want, so I'm happy with this method:

```
records = MeasureValue.objects.filter(month=month).values()
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(records)
// use calc_value to set percentile on each row, using scipy's rankdata
```

However, I then need to retrieve each percentile value from the dataframe, and set it back onto the model instances. Right now I do this by iterating over the dataframe's rows, and updating each instance:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    mv = MeasureValue.objects.get(org=row.org, month=month)
    if (row.percentile is None) or np.isnan(row.percentile):
        row.percentile = None
    mv.percentile = row.percentile
    mv.save()
```

This is unsurprisingly quite slow. Is there any efficient Django way to speed it up, by making a single database write rather than tens of thousands? I have [checked the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once), but can't see one.

Comment: Have you looked at [`QuerySet.update()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#update)?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I'm not sure it helps, given that I need to set a different value on every row...?

Comment: oh I missed that requirement, sorry

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Atomic transactions can reduce the time spent in the loop:

```
from django.db import transaction

with transaction.atomic():
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        mv = MeasureValue.objects.get(org=row.org, month=month)

        if (row.percentile is None) or np.isnan(row.percentile): 
            # if it's already None, why set it to None?
            row.percentile = None

        mv.percentile = row.percentile
        mv.save()
```

Django’s default behavior is to run in autocommit mode. Each query is immediately committed to the database, unless a transaction is actives.

By using `with transaction.atomic()`  all the inserts are grouped into a single transaction. The time needed to commit the transaction is amortized over all the enclosed insert statements and so the time per insert statement is greatly reduced.

Comment: Thanks. Why does this reduce the time? The documentation isn't helping https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/transactions/#controlling-transactions-explicitly

Comment: Because the queries are combined into a single large query, that is only executed once. Lets say saving to the database takes 10 ms, if you save 100 objects running autocommit, that takes 10 ms * 100, but if you use a transaction it will only take 10 ms * 1 (rougly)

Comment: very help full answer. actually I was looking for something else but got very good alternative

Answer (score 37):

As of Django 2.2, you can use the [`bulk_update()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-update) queryset method to efficiently update the given fields on the provided model instances, generally with one query:

```
objs = [
    Entry.objects.create(headline='Entry 1'),
    Entry.objects.create(headline='Entry 2'),
]
objs[0].headline = 'This is entry 1'
objs[1].headline = 'This is entry 2'
Entry.objects.bulk_update(objs, ['headline'])
```

In older versions of Django you could use [`update()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update) with `Case`/`When`, e.g.:

```
from django.db.models import Case, When

Entry.objects.filter(
    pk__in=headlines  # `headlines` is a pk -> headline mapping
).update(
    headline=Case(*[When(pk=entry_pk, then=headline)
                    for entry_pk, headline in headlines.items()]))
```

Comment: Thanks for putting the older version in there. I don't have access to `bulk_update` so getting clarity on the `update` call was reassuring.

Comment: Is `Case`, `When` faster than `transactions` ?

Comment: I found more detail on the behind the scenes of this here https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/mjpbij/running_a_bulk_update_efficiently_with_django/

Answer (score 1):

In my case, we need `Value`

```
headlines is a pk -> headline mapping `{1, 'some_val1', 2, 'some_val2', ...}
```

```
from django.db.models import Case, When, Value

Entry.objects.filter(
pk__in=headlines  
).update(
headline=Case(*[When(pk=entry_pk, then=Value(headline))
                for entry_pk, headline in headlines.items()]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, attempting @Eugene Yarmash 's answer I found I got this error:

`FieldError: Joined field references are not permitted in this query`

But I believe iterating `update` is still quicker than multiple saves, and I expect using a transaction should also expedite.

So, for versions of Django that don't offer `bulk_update`, assuming the same data used in Eugene's answer, where `headlines` is a pk -> headline mapping:

```
from django.db import transaction

with transaction.atomic():
    for entry_pk, headline in headlines.items():
        Entry.objects.filter(pk=entry_pk).update(headline=headline)
```