# Updating selection of objects, each with a different value in bulk (Django)

Tags: django, django-orm

Imagine I have a python dictionary where keys are existing user ids, and values are scores to be added to those users' existing scores.

For example: `{1: 1580, 4: 540, 2: 678}` (this could stretch to `n` k,v pairs)

I need to update the scores of all these user objects (updated_score = original_score + new_score). One way to do it is iteratively, like so:

```
from django.db.models import F
scores = {1: 1580, 4: 540, 2: 678}
for user_id,score_to_add in scores.iteritems():
    UserProfile.objects.filter(user_id=user_id).update(score=F('score')+score_to_add)
```

But that's multiple DB calls. Can I do it in a single call? An illustrative example would be great. As you would have guessed, this is for a Django project.

Comment: Never used it, but django-bulk-update might help? https://github.com/aykut/django-bulk-update

Comment: I don't think this is feasible since you need a different value in each row. As @DA-- said, you should use this package or wrap the `for` loop in a `transaction.atomic()` context.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Something like that:

```
from django.db.models import F
from django.db import transaction

with transaction.atomic():
    scores = {1: 1580, 4: 540, 2: 678}
    for user_id,score_to_add in scores:
        UserProfile.objects.filter(user_id=user_id).update(score=F('score')+score_to_add)
```

More on this [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic)

You can take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36751395/update-multiple-objects-at-once-in-django) too.

[UPDATE]:

TL;DR: It'll **not make one db query** but it will be faster cause each query lacks the database overhead.

As the docs and @ahmed in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36751395/update-multiple-objects-at-once-in-django) say:

> Django’s default behavior is to run in autocommit mode. Each query is
>   immediately committed to the database, unless a transaction is
>   active.
>
> By using `with transaction.atomic()` all the inserts are grouped into a
>   single transaction. The time needed to commit the transaction is
>   amortized over all the enclosed insert statements and so the time per
>   insert statement is greatly reduced.

Comment: So to be exact, does this imply a single DB operation?

Comment: Well "kind of" a single DB operation (updated my answer). Without the DB overhead each time. I don't believe what you ask is feasible with Django ORM, unless you use the `extra` to write custom SQL query.

Comment: Yea I read the docs you linked to as well. I think this would primarily help me avoid race conditions. This could perhaps be called an optimization as well - but what happens when the dictionary is large? The updates being performed on the table would block all others. So technically, as `n` scales, the atomic nature of the transaction comes back to bite us. Don't you think? And one can avoid this scenario if it was a simple for loop.

Comment: Quoting from [here](https://makandracards.com/makandra/31937-differences-between-transactions-and-locking): *Nothing special happens if the "same" transaction [...] runs at the same time. They will simply run at the same time. There is no guarantee of the order*. So, in my belief, the size of `n` will not affect updates on the table. That would be another great SO question.

Answer (score 0):

`transaction.atomic()` proposed by @nik_m is good idea, but also you should get records from database in single request.

```
from django.db.models import F
from django.db import transaction

with transaction.atomic():
    scores = {1: 1580, 4: 540, 2: 678}
    users_to_update = UserProfile.objects.filter(
        user_id__in=scores.keys()
    ) 
    for user in users_to_update:
        user.update(score=F('score') + scores[user.user_id])
```

Comment: This isn't any better; in fact it does extra queries. nik's version doesn't require fetching the objects at all.

Comment: @DanielRoseman are you sure? His version iterates over dict and does a fetch for each record (using ```.filter()```). Doesn't it?

Comment: No. filter by itself doesn't do a fetch. It's just one UPDATE call per item.