# how to update django database entry based on request.POST data

Tags: python, django

I am working with django on `updating` my `QueryDict` into the database. This `QueryDict` comes from a `request.POST` method via the `html` interface.

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['foo'], 'student_attend': ['Select', 'Select', 'Select'], 'final_student_pk': ['7', '8', '12'], 'submit_student_attendance': ['']}>
```

What I was attempting to do, was to update my `database object` `student_attend` column based on the `final_student_pk` value. Meaning to say, I was attempting the below:

```
if 'submit_student_attendance' in request.POST:
    to_update = AddNewSchedule.objects.filter(pk=request.POST['final_student_pk'])
    to_update.update(student_attend=request.POST['student_attend'])
```

This does do the job of updating my `AddNewSchedule` database table. However, it only updates the last `pk` item. (ie: it only updates item 12 in the database). It does not loop through `pk 7` and `pk8` to update the database as well.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the answer was pretty simple.. All I had to do was to use `getlist`. I made reference here: https://kite.com/python/docs/django.http.request.QueryDict.

```
    if 'submit_student_attendance' in request.POST:
        print(request.POST.getlist('student_attend'), request.POST.getlist('final_student_pk'))
        from django.db import transaction
        for key, value in zip(request.POST.getlist('final_student_pk'), request.POST.getlist('student_attend')):
            with transaction.atomic():
                to_update = AddNewSchedule.objects.filter(pk=key)
                to_update.update(student_attend=value)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not do this in one query because the values are unique for each instance. Try looping through instances and updating one at a time. You can use `transaction.atomic` to reduce db overhead.

```
if 'submit_student_attendance' in request.POST:
    id_list = request.POST.getlist('final_student_pk')
    instance_list = request.POST.getlist('student_attend')

    with transaction.atomic():
        for instance, id in zip(instance_list, id_list):
            to_update = AddNewSchedule.objects.filter(pk=id)
            to_update.update(student_attend=instance)
```

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42733306/3968623) for more details.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. but this doesn't seem to solve the problem. it is still not updating the database for all entries.

Comment: Oh. I made a mistake. It should have been `getlist()`.

Comment: Updated my answer.