# Django: How to trigger a function whenever certain objects are modified from the wagtail interface

Tags: django, triggers, wagtail, django-signals, wagtail-admin

I have a long list of "Quotation" objects.

The price of a quotation depends on dozens of children (and grand children) objects. The lowest one being the rate/hour.

When I change the children objects of a quotation like the rate/hour, the quotation price changes.

I would like to recalculate the price of each quotation that is impacted by any change I make on their consistuant objects automatically. I am using Wagtail for the object admin.

I am not sure about the way to do that, should I use signals? Wagtail hooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wagtail models and pages are just Django models.

Are all children (and grand children) of the same model? In that case you could just register a post_save signal on the child model, but in general, I'd recommend using post_save only for non-mutating actions like sending an email when an object changes, unless you take the following things into consideration:

- This kind of processing can become very slow very quickly. If you have multiple quotations, you'll need to use an [atomic transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36751395/update-multiple-objects-at-once-in-django/36751534), otherwise you'll make a new db connection when saving every quotation.
- You'll also need to [prefetch](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) children and grandchildren to prevent multiple database calls.
- When saving other models inside a post_save you run the risk of creating an endless loop of post_save signals.

I think a better way would be to add a @property called `price` on Quotation instead of storing the price in the database:

```
class Quotation(models.Model):
    # Model fields here
    ...

    @property
    def price(self):
        return sum([child.price for child in self.children])
```

This will only calculate a price when you call `quotation.price`. You could speed up this calculation by prefetching children when receiving Quotations.